# kivy adding attribute manager to a tabbedpanelitem

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to have a a screen inside a tabbed panels "space".

When i try to switch between screens, i get an AttributeError:

```
"AttributeError: 'TabbedTest' object has no attribute 'manager'"
```

I'm not sure how to add the screenmanager to the tabbedpanels attributes.
I'm unsure of how i create a reference to the tabbedpanel in the screenmanager or how i add the property.

**Pythonfile**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen 
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout


class TabbedTest(TabbedPanel):
    pass
class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass
class Firstscreen(Screen):
    pass

class myapp(App):

    def build(self):
        
    root = FloatLayout()
    self.tabbedtest = TabbedTest()
    root.add_widget(self.tabbedtest)

    # Create the screen manager
    self.sm = ScreenManager()
    self.sm.add_widget(MainScreen(name='main'))
    self.sm.add_widget(Firstscreen(name='first'))
    root.add_widget(self.sm)
    
    return root

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myapp().run()
```

**my.kv**

```
<TabbedTest>
    do_default_tab: False
    TabbedPanelItem:
        text:"test"

        MainScreen:
            Button:
                text: 'first'
                on_press: root.manager.current = 'first' #Problemarea

<Firstscreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            text:"first"
        Button:
            text: 'Back to main'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'main'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the `Screens` inside the `TabbedPanelItem`, then you should put the `ScreenManager` inside the `TabbedPanelItem`. Here is a modified version of your `kv` that does that:

```
<TabbedTest>
    do_default_tab: False
    TabbedPanelItem:
        text:"test"
        
        ScreenManager:
            id: manager  # for easy access

            MainScreen:
                name: 'main'
                Button:
                    text: 'first'
                    on_press: manager.current = 'first'  # use manager id
            Firstscreen:
                name: 'first'

<Firstscreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            text:"first"
        Button:
            text: 'Back to main'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'main'
```

Then your `build()` method can be simply:

```
def build(self):
    return TabbedTest()
```